# Design issue in C

Tags: c, struct, header

I'm struggling with a design issue, and I'm trying to find the "Best Practice" answer for my situation.

Say I have a file called `Logger.c` (And `Logger.h`) that is responsible for logging actions in my program.

I want logger to be referenced by all my modules, so each module's has a 
`#include Logger.h`.

Say I have a module called `NTFS.c` that is responsible for interaction with the NTFS FS, This module has special structs that are defined in its header, for example: `NTFS_Partition.`

Here is the problem:

On one hand, I want logger to be able to print to a log file a formatted representation of NTFS_Partition, and by that I must `#include NTFS.h` in `Logger.h`.

```
(Inside Logger.h)

#include NTFS_Partition
VOID Log_Partition(NTFS_Partition *part);
```

On the other hand, I am not sure Logger should re-reference modules that reference him.

Currently I'm seeing a two main choices:

1.Logger.h includes NTFS.h, and NTFS.c include Logger.h (This works)

2.I create a new header file called NTFS_Types.h that would be shared accross all the
 modules, and would only contain the deceleration of NTFS structs (like NTFS_Partition).

Thanks a lot,
Michael.

Comment: I prefer option 2, because I loath hidden circular module dependencies like this. If `Logger` actually decides to call an API in `NTFS.h`, you might run into real problems of a subtle nature.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Please see my comment below about option 2. Are you aware about more options for this situation ?

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++?  Also, what happened to the double quotes (or angle brackets) around the file names you `#include`?

Comment: I'm coding in C (I wrote it in the title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear whether you are coding in C or C++; I'm going to assume C (so no overloaded function names, etc).  It seems to me that you need to 'forward declare' your structures.  In `Logger.h`, you write:

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H_INCLUDED
#define LOGGER_H_INCLUDED

struct NTFS_Partition;     // No details - just the name (3 times)
struct FAT16_Partition;
struct FAT32_Partition;

...

void Log_NTFS_Partition(struct NTFS_Partition *part);
void Log_FAT16_Partition(struct FAT16_Partition *part);
void Log_FAT32_Partition(struct FAT32_Partition *part);

#endif // LOGGER_H_INCLUDED
```

This is all the information that a general client (of `Logger.h`) needs to know.

If a specific client is dealing with NTFS partitions, then it will not only include `Logger.h` but also `NTFS.h`, which will provide the full definition of `struct NTFS_Partition { ... };`, so the client can create instances of the structure and populate it with data.  The code that implements the logging, `Logger.c`, will also include `Logger.h` and `NTFS.h` (and `FAT16.h` and `FAT32.h`), of course, so that it too can reference the members of the structures.

The header for a service (such as `Logger.h`) should provide the minimal amount of information that the clients of the service need for compilation.  The implementation file may need more information, but can collect the extra information from headers that provide it.

One advantage of using the `struct tag` notation is precisely that it can be repeated as often as necessary without messing anything up. If you don't have C11, you can't repeat a `typedef`, so if you write:

```
typedef struct NTFS_Partition NTFS_Partition;
```

you must only include that line once.  The difficulty is making sure that it is only defined once.  For that, you probably use a header such as `FSTypes.h` to define the file-system `typedefs` that is properly protected by header guards and is included in any file that needs any of the `typedefs`.  You can then reference the types without the preceding `struct` keyword.

If you code in C++, the `typedef` isn't necessary; `struct NTFS_Partition;` declares that there is such a structure type and also declares `NTFS_Partition` as a name for that type.  If your code is bilingual, use the `typedef` version; it works in both C and C++.

Note that if your functions such as `Log_NTFS_Partition()` take an actual structure instead of a pointer to a structure, then you have to have the definition of the structure in scope.  If the functions only take pointers, though, a forward declaration is sufficient.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have two last question: Is it a best practice that implementation of modules (The .c file) would be circular referencing ? In your example NTFS.c would include Logger.h and Logger.c would include NTFS.h.

Comment: My second question: Would you create a new header called FS_Types to hold all the struct declerations ? Or would you leave each strcut for its .h file (For example: struct NTFS_Partition would stay in NTFS.h)

Comment: Q1: You avoid circular references when you can.  When you can't, and it appears it will be hard here, you try to neutralize them as much as you can.  One alternative is that NTFS.h declares the log function for the NTFS partition, but then Logger.h is not the complete description of the services provided by Logger.c. I don't see it as a huge problem here — but keep a careful eye on things.  If it becomes pervasive, then your losing your modularity.

Comment: Q2: My suggestion of FSTypes.h was for the `typedef struct NTFS_Partition NTFS_Partition;` lines (which declare the existence of the given structure type and create a typedef name for the structure type — but do *not* define the contents of those structures.  I'd avoid such a header if I could — but it depends on where those typedefs are going to be created and used.  And I'd try to avoid an omnibus 'all project structure typedefs' header.  One way around the problem is to always use `struct WhatNot` everywhere; I believe that's what the Linux kernel guidelines require, and it has its merits.

Comment: Ok this is what I'v done: In Logger.h I forward declared "struct NTFS_Partition" and did not include NTFS.h. In NTFS.h I declared the entire struct like this "typedef struct{PVOID pVbr;} NTFS_Partition". In Main.c I included "Logger.h" and "NTFS.h", When "Include Logger.h" is bellow "Include NTFS.h" I get the following error: "Incomplete type is not allowed". When I reverse the order of Includes the error disappears .. Any idea why this is happening ? P.S I really appreciate your help, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Works for me and for your code. The only gotcha to watch for is `void SomeFunction(struct PreviouslyUnknown *ptr);` where the structure tag was not declared outside the function prototype.  The scope of that is just the function declaration. You should get a warning. If you do, simply add `struct PreviouslyUnknown;` before the function prototype and you're good to go. (`xx.c:1:26: warning: ‘struct PreviouslyUnknown’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
xx.c:1:26: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]`

Comment: I did declare "struct NTFS_Partition" outside of my function. But that is not the problem. The problem is when a third module (Main.c) Includes Logger.h and NTFS.h i has 2 declarations of NTFS_Partition. The first one in NTFS.h (The full one) and the second in Logger.h (The forward deceleration). It seems to use the deceleration of the lowest Include, therefor when Logger.h is included after NTFS.h I receive a "Incomplete type is not allowed" error when trying to access the fields of a NTFS_Partition struct.

Comment: The last one I figured out by myself. The trick is in the full deceleration in NTFS.h I cannot write "typedef struct{PVOID pVbr;} NTFS_Partition", instead I should write  "typedef struct NTFS_Partition {PVOID pVbr;} NTFS_Partition". Notice that in the second deceleration I added "NTFS_Partition" before the curly brackets :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shared header where all your structs are defined.

```
// structs.h
struct NTFS_Partition { .. };
struct FAT32_Partition { .. };
struct FAT16_Partition { .. };
```

Include it in `logger.h`.

```
// logger.h
#include "structs.h"
VOID Log_Partition(NTFS_Partition *part);
VOID Log_Partition(FAT32_Partition *part);
VOID Log_Partition(FAT16_Partition *part);
```

And include the `logger.h` in various source files.

```
// NTFS.c
#include "logger.h"
// FAT32.c
#include "logger.h"
// FAT16.c
#include "logger.h"
```

In C++, it's better to keep different irrelevant class definitions in different header files. But in C, placing different struct definitions in separate headers is probably an overkill.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The only thing that "bugs" me with this option is that I have heard more than once that a header file should contain ALL the needed data to compile and link against a module. By taking NTFS_PARTITION out of NTFS.h, I am forcing a future programmer to include "NTFS.h" and "Structs.h" in order to properly compile and link. I am aware this is a trade off, but I would be glad to know if there is a better option.

Comment: @MichaelEngstler: Just let `NTFS.h` include `Structs.h`.